# How to set HTTP proxy in ChromeDriver of Selenium 2?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

how do I set a HTTP proxy for Selenium 2's ChromeDriver in Java? I know how to do it for the FirefoxDriver using a FirefoxProfile, but there doesn't seem to be a ChromeProfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply set the chrome proxy prefs at the chrome level. Unlike the firefox driver, the chrome driver does not reset chrome prefs each time it initiates a session.